# Added Space Below Divs

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css-float, space

I have a layout in which the navigation is a set of divs stacked on top of each other. Typical stoy, "It works with every browser ever except the worst ones, IE." I want it to not have any space in between the divs in IE.

Here is the URL: http://www.drmsmaggio.com/

I had this problem before when I didn't declare the doctype, but that isn't the problem here because there is a doctype set.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would move to a 4.01 strict doctype instead of the transitional one.  Transistional triggers quirks mode in all the browsers which means that you end up with interesting little problems like this.

Second, I would use a reset style sheet to remove most of the inherited padding / margins.  Then I would set those padding / margins using CSS where it was necessary.

btw, you should see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611704/how-can-i-achieve-a-consistent-layout-in-all-browsers).  Joel Coehoorn had a great response about how to build consistently rendered pages.

Comment: You were right, and that is what I had to do last time. I use DotNetNuke at work which makes a million choices I would not make on my own. I manually set the doctype to XHTML 1.0 transitional and that did the trick. Thanks for the link, too.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please remember to mark the answer as the correct one.  You get points for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a little bottom margin to your divs and get rid of the 'spacer' divs that sit between your menu divs.

margin-bottom: 7px;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like right after "What is Chiropractic?" there is a paragraph with text that is black.  That should be some of your problem ;o)

Comment: Nope, that is a totally unrelated problem to the one asked. Thanks anyway.